# the type name text does not exist in the type xmlnodetype

Tags: c#, xml, readxml

I am trying to read a certain section from an xml file in C#. I tried using this code here but I get a compiler error under the `Text` in `XmlNodeType.Text` but the weird thing is it comes up with intellisense and gives the same error with everything else like `Element` ,`Comment` etc.. what am I missing?

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlDoc);
List<string> paths = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Paths")
        foreach(XmlNodeType.Text aa in reader.ReadInnerXml())
            paths.Add(aa);
}
reader.Close();
```

XML file

```
<Config>
    <Paths>
      <Input>C:\</Input>
      <Output>C:\</Output>
      <Log>\Logs</Log>
    </Paths>

    <SystemOwnerRoles>
      <Supplier>SUPPLIER</Supplier>
      <Mop>MOP</Mop>
    </SystemOwnerRoles>
</Config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlNodeType` is an enum. `XmlNodeType.Text` is a value, not a type, but you're trying to use it as the type of the `aa` variable. Furthermore `ReaderInnerXml()` returns a `string`, so it's not clear how you expect to iterate over it.

Do you *have* to use `XmlTextReader` for this? Almost all XML work is simpler using LINQ to XML. For example, this is all I think you need:

```
var paths = XDocument.Load(xmlDoc)
                     .Descendants("Paths")
                     .Elements()
                     .Select(element => (string) element)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: no i dont have to use `XMLTextReader` its just what i came across first never used XML before and not that great at `LINQ` but ill give this a try

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: It's *much* easier to use LINQ to XML than `XmlReader` - and if you're uncomfortable with LINQ in general, I strongly suggest you try to improve, as it's *incredibly* useful.

Comment: i got an exception when running this, it said data at root level is invalid at line 1 position 1 am i writing my xml wrong?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: I'd assumed that `xmlDoc` was the string that you'd loaded already. If it's actually the filename, you need `XDocument.Load` instead. I'll edit my answer. (Hint: this is where a [mcve] would have removed any ambiguity. I should have checked the `XmlTextReader` documentation to see which constructor you were calling, but the clearer you can make your question, the better.)